# Node.js script loading not loading from browser (outsider) but loading from command (localhost)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have successfully installed Node.JS and [Balloons.IO](https://github.com/gravityonmars/Balloons.IO/) chatroom on my linux based vps (with SSH). When typing `curl http://mydomain.com:9191/` in the ssh command I can see the html is loaded. But, when trying to reach the same page from my browser it takes some time loading then says page could not be reached. Any idea why ?

Comment: Can you ping the domain from your machine (does DNS resolve)? Do firewall rules restrict that port (does the VPS allow outside traffic to access `9191`)?

Comment: yes the domain itself works fine and I can see the logo I uploaded to the home page

Comment: have you tried accessing that port over the network, via something like `telnet mydomain.com 9191` or using `curl mydomain.com:9191` from a remote host?

Comment: curl returned curl: (7) couldn't connect to host whne using this port but loads fine without it

Comment: telnet cant open connection on this port as said

Comment: Sounds like a firewall issue to me, ensure you are allowing remote traffic on this port. Also check to make sure your app is listening correctly with `sudo netstat -anp | grep :9191` and you should see it listening to `0.0.0.0:9191` or something similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### My common diagnostic steps:

---

#### 1) Check that your app is actually listening on the port it should be, you can do this with:

```
sudo netstat -anp | grep :9191
```

You should see your app listening to `0.0.0.0:9191` or `your.ip.address.here:9191` if you see something like `127.0.0.1:9191`, then it is only listening locally so you won't be able to reach it.

#### 2) Ensure your firewall isn't blocking these ports, if you are using `iptables` you can check with:

```
sudo iptables --list
```

This will print the rules for your firewall and you can check if you port is blocked (or allowed).

#### 3) Try connecting locally. My third step is generally to try it locally with `curl`, you did this step already but for other landing here you can do something like:

```
curl http://localhost:9191/
```

and see what you get back

#### 4) Try connecting remotely. If everything above looks fine, try running a verbose curl from a remote host and see what you get:

```
curl -v http://mydomain.com:9191/
```

This will show header and body output so you can see if the remote host even responds; if it doesn't then check if the raw port is even accessable with telnet:

```
telnet mydomain.com 9191
```

which if successful will print something like:

```
Trying your.ip.address.here...
Connected to mydomain.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

If it fails it will just hang at `Trying...` if it fails then your firewall is blocking the port, your host is blocking the port, or your app isn't listening to the port. If your above tests passed then contact your host because something else may be up and you should be able to get support from them.

Comment: +1! Thank you so much! I indeed added a rule in iptables to accept the port and it works now! It was the firewall